# How to set observable properties async in typescript?

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I have a couple of properties that are fetched asynchronously. I would like to bind the result of these properties to a view in my application. However, the `get` properties see the view model's variables as null. How can I bind them after the result has arrived? In the code below, `userEmail` and `appVersion` are null/undefined in their respective get functions.

```
export class AccountViewModel extends Observable {
    private _userEmail : Email;
    private _appVersion : string;

    constructor() {
        super();

        appVersion.getVersionName().then(
            (result) =>
            {
                this._appVersion = result;
                console.log(this._appVersion);
            });

        firebase.getCurrentUser().then(
            (result) => {
                this._userEmail = new Email(result.email);
            });
    }

    get userEmail(): string {
        return this._userEmail != null ? this._userEmail.Value : "";
    }

    get appVersion(): string {
        return this._appVersion;
    }

    public logout() {
        firebase.logout().then((result) => {
            Navigator.navigateTo({
                moduleName : "views/register/register",
                backstackVisible : false,
                clearHistory : true
            })
        }).catch((error) => {
            dialogs.alert({
                title: "Error",
                message: "A system error occurred trying to logout.",
                okButtonText: "Ok"
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how nativescript works under the hood but if it automatically raises change events for you, you probably would have to define setters that it could hook into. You're changing the backing value, but you're probably bypassing a lot of the builtin mechanisms. That or you probably have to raise the notify events manually.

Answer (score 0):

The Observable class has a notifyPropertyChange method :)

```
export class AccountViewModel extends Observable {
    private _appVersion : string;

    constructor() {
        super();

        appVersion.getVersionName().then((result) => {
            this._appVersion = result;
            this.notifyPropertyChange("appVersion", this._appVersion);
        });
    }

    get appVersion() : string {
        return this._appVersion;
    }

    public logout() {
        firebase.logout().then((result) => {
            Navigator.navigateTo({
                moduleName : "views/register/register",
                backstackVisible : false,
                clearHistory : true
            })
        }).catch((error) => {
            dialogs.alert({
                title: "Error",
                message: "A system error occurred trying to logout.",
                okButtonText: "Ok"
            });
        });
    }
}
```